# InstallShield Basic MSI InstallDIR

Tags: installshield

I am trying to give my users the ability to select the drive they want to load our software to.  Instead of just giving them the InstallChangeFolder dialog I am attempting to just list the drives that are available to load on. I have done this in an InstallScript project before but now we are trying to move to MSI.  Basically the flow will be they select the drive and then we append our root path to that drive.  Does anyone know of any good tutorials that would explain how to create a custom dialog for changing the installdir and wiring up in all of the custom actions and sequences. If it matters I am using InstallShield 2013 and a Basic MSI Project

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to hardcode your installation path? That seems like enforcing bad design decisions on your customers.

The default method of allowing the user to pick the installation path is the standard method, for a good reason.

Answer (score 2):

I agree hard coding the path is a bad design, however in order to achieve what you want just create new custom action by going through custom action wizard selecting installscript file, copy your code of install script and add place newly created custom action in the correct sequence.